# Is there a way to decompile an Ocaml executable file into Source code?

Tags: ocaml, decompiling

Is there a way to fully or partially decompile an `*.out` executable Ocaml file into source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml compiles to native code and there are no decompilers known to me that decompile binaries to OCaml. So the answer is no in practice. But, of course, you can write a decompiler yourself. It will not be an easy task though.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no". There is nothing about OCaml that makes this particularly easier than with any other language. There are no standard OCAML tools that do this, and I wouldn't expect there to be.

I'm not clear what you mean by `*.out`. Are you talking about a native executable or a byte code executable? There is a tool sometimes named `ocamldumpobj` that dumps out the codes of an OCaml bytecode file. This looks nothing like the source, but it's at least a representation of the code in a slightly abstract form.

For native executables, you really can't expect much. The original source code has been passed through many, many (uninvertible) transformations. You can use a disassembler to look at the machine code. Again, this looks nothing like the source.

Comment: I assume he's referring to the default executable name of  `a.out`.

Comment: Why the `*` then? If so, a.out is a native executable (hence not very decompilable at all IMHO).